# Dynamic Form/Layout and Summer 23

Tags: dynamic-forms, record-page-setting, summer-23

I have a problem since the preparation of the release Summer 23.

In the Person Account record page we have a Details tab using the old Page Layout but recently we added a new tab with Dynamic Layout with a few fields.

But when the New quick action button is pressed and we select the Person Account Record Page in Summer 23 orgs only the new Dynamic Form tab fields is shown and not the Detail tabs page layout fields.

We checked that in the Spring 23 orgs the details tab fields are shown.

Do you have the same problem?

Thank you in advance.